# Trying to associate 4 tables with one mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

So, I'm a novice php/mysql developer and I'm trying to learn more by creating a text based gaming application (a little context). I'm building an armory and the armor uses 4 tables. The goal of this query it to show the user the items they have equiped.

1. user table- hold user information (user_id)
2. items table- hold all the non specific information about in game items (item_id)
3. inventory table- holds the information about a users inventory. Association between users table and items table.
4. Armor/Weapons table- holds the specific information about armor and weapons (arm_name/wep_name)

I want to be able to select the users equipped items from the inventory and return the names of the items. This is the best I've been able to come up with, but I can't seem to get everything into a single row. Can anyone point me in the right direction to return the item_id of both items along with their names? I really appreciate it.

```
select weapons.item_id, weapons.wep_name, armor.arm_name, armor.item_id from inventory
join users on users.user_id = inventory.user_id
left join weapons on weapons.item_id = inventory.item_id
left join armor on armor.item_id = inventory.item_id
where users.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: This isnt really an answer,.....but if you use a PHP framework like Laravel....stuff like this becomes infinitely easier, with relationships etc.....but I understand you're trying to learn, so just ignore me.....but if you get frustrated....look into the various PHP frameworks around.

Comment: If the user has more than 1 item, how would those items be mapped to a single row?  Currently your query looks like it returns every item for the user.  Isn't that what you need?

Comment: the problem is that most likely every user will have more than 1 item (so 1 row per item seems reasonable), so why do you want to return a single row?

Comment: If you are using mysql workbench create an EER diagram and paste the picture here. It will be much easier for us to answer

Comment: Question: how does an entry in `inventory` indicate whether `item_id` refers to a weapon or armor? Do you ensure that there are no overlaps in IDs between those tables?

Answer (score 0):

To get everything into a single row, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wep_name) AS weapons, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT arm_name) AS armor
FROM users
JOIN inventory ON users.user_id = inventory.user_id
left join weapons on weapons.item_id = inventory.item_id
left join armor on armor.item_id = inventory.item_id
where users.user_id = 1;
```